# Unable to get the value of the property using javascript

Tags: javascript

I get the error "Unable to get the value of the property 'checked'. object is null or undefined." when clicking a checkbox.

The form's name is 'test', and I want to display more input fields based on the first check box being checked, if they pass by it then I do not want the other fields displayed.

Here's the script:

```
function showhidefield()
{
    if (document.test.submode.checked) {
        document.getElementById("hideablearea").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hideablearea").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here's my input line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="submode" onclick="showhidefield()">
```

Is there a way I can make my JS more solid so it works on this other web page and on any browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will not always be a `<form>` on the page with the name `"test"`.

You can make it work without an id by using `this` to reference the current element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="submode" onclick="showhidefield(this, 'hideablearea')">
```

JavaScript:

```
function showhidefield(element, id)
{
  var node = document.getElementById(id);

  if (node) {
    node.style.display = element.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/eyirub/1/)

The first argument to the function is the checkbox itself and the second argument is the id of the element you wish to show or hide.

Comment: The problem with this is the page loads with the check box checked and the extra fields showing.  I need the default to be no show unless checked....  So would I switch the block and none order?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Then you add `style="display:none;"` on the `#hideablearea` and remove `checked="checked"` from the checkbox element. @user2066907

Answer (score 1):

Put an ID on the checkbox, and use `getElementById`. This is more reliable than other methods, since IDs are required to be unique.

Comment: So I add id="submode" to the input field and

Comment: Can you show me how to use the getElementById in my case?  Thank you~